# Nginx Configuration for btcpay server

Tags: nginx, debian, reverse-proxy, btcpay-server

I'm trying to have a btcpayserver instance running on my website server machine, can't seem to get it working. Keeps throwing a 403 error. Here is my server block in /etc/nginx/conf.d/myserver
`server {
server_name myserver
listen 443;

```
    root /var/www/html/;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver/privkey.pem;


    access_log /var/log/nginx/btcpay.access;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/btcpay.error;
    client_max_body_size 100M;

    # Here is the main BTCPay Server application
    location / {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:49392;
            autoindex on;
    }

    # Include the next two stanzas if and only if you want to expose your lightning gRPC & RPC interfaces to the internet
    #location /lnrpc.Lightning {
    #        grpc_pass grpcs://127.0.0.1:10009;
    #}

    #location /lnd-rest/btc/ {
    #        rewrite ^/lnd-rest/btc/(.*) /$1 break;
    #        proxy_pass https://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    #}

    # Include this stanza if you are planning to set up Ride The Lightning (RTL)
    location /rtl/ {
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:3000/rtl/;
    }
```

}`this is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/myserver`server {
listen 443;
server_name myserver;

```
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver/fullchain.pem;
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myserver/privkey.pem;

location / {
    root /var/www/html/;
    index index.html index.php;
    autoindex on;
}
```

}

Have already checked the permissions nginx is the owner and group, have already confirmed that 49392 is listening for requests, not sure why it's not working.
`